# Oxidation of substituted cyclic ketone using permanganate

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, organic-oxidation

[image]

From what I had learnt, reaction of this with $\ce{KMnO4}$ should give a dicarboxylic acid after cleavage of the carbon-carbon bond. But apparently this is the reaction that happens:

[image]

Why is there a ketone on one side?

Also, if a dicarboxylic acid WAS formed, which side would the carbonyl group remain with? I've studied for linear ketones on strong oxidation (for eg $\ce{KMnO4}$ or nitric acid) the carbonyl group stays with the shorter alkyl group. Here, what would happen?

Comment: The more stable enol determines the direction of the oxidation. If the dicarbxylic acid WERE formed, it be 2-R-adipic acid without a keto carbonyl.

Comment: Yes, 2-R-adipic acid is exactly what I expected. Sorry though, I didn't understand what you mean by more stable enol. Are you giving the justification of this: "the carbonyl group stays with the shorter alkyl group"?